# Trying to setup Bcrypt on Spring Web app but I keep getting redirected back to the login page

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-mvc, bcrypt

I am making a Spring Web, java, MySQL, thymeleaf, maven project where I try to encode the passwords to the database. But every time I try to login or register a new user, I get redirected to the login page.

UserDetailsService

```
@Service
    public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = userRepository.getUserByEmail(username);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/allTasks", true)
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                                .usernameParameter("email")
                                .passwordParameter("password")
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

HomeController (essential parts):

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam("email") String email,
                        @RequestParam("password") String password,
                        Model model,
                        HttpSession session) {
        try {
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password)
            );
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/allTasks";
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Email or password invalid");
            return "login";
        }
    }

@PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestParam("user-firstname") String newFirstName,
                          @RequestParam("user-lastname") String newLastName,
                          @RequestParam("user-email") String newEmail,
                          @RequestParam("user-password") String newPassword,
                          HttpSession session)
    {
        if ( session.getAttribute("user") == null )
        {
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        //lave en ny User
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setFirstName(newFirstName);
        newUser.setLastName(newLastName);
        newUser.setEmail(newEmail);
        // Encrypt the password before setting it
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword);
        newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

        //Gem ny User
        userRepository.addUser(newUser);

        //Tilbage til start så man kan logge ind
        return "start";
    }

@PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@RequestParam("first_name") String firstname,
                               @RequestParam("last_name") String lastname,
                               @RequestParam("email") String email,
                               @RequestParam("password") String password,
                               Model model,
                               HttpSession session)
    {
        //Check if user with mail already exists
        if ( !userRepository.checkIfUserExists(email) )
        {
            User user = new User(firstname, lastname, email, password);
            userRepository.addUser(user);
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/allTasks";
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Email already in use");
            return "register";
        }
    }
```

Everything worked before I began experimenting with encryption, so I think the problem is in the SecurityConfig or CustomUserDetailsService? Or what do you think?

I tried having the encryption directly in the userRepository addTask, but it gave the same problem.

I tried to have the verification happen manually in the userRepository but it gave me some problems with the encryption.

Comment: Remove your login method, Spring Security should handle that. Next to that your `register` doesn't encrypt passwords and for existing users you will need to change the passwords in the database to the encrypted ones